# Using mixin inside the same selector in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to achieve something like this in LESS:

```css
.a {
    // some properties
}

.b {
    .a {
        .a();
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, because it takes the `.a()` from the closest scope, which is `.b .a` in this case. I need this quirky rule just to overwrite another context for `.a` to use the default `.a` styles.

Can I call a mixin of the same selector in LESS? Or maybe there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate mixin class and refer to it in both non-inside-b and inside-b cases.

To prevent outputting the mixin class, use the functional mixin-definition [syntax](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin):

```
.a() {}
```

Also, mixins can be defined inside a dummy id as a [namespace](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-namespaces), and that mixins shouldn’t be output too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy!